# How to break up command in CircleCI yml to multiple lines?

Tags: yaml, circleci

I have a CircleCI configuration file that looks like so:

```
# Customize test commands
test:
  override:
    - docker run -e VAR1=$VAR! -e VAR2=$VAR2 -e $VAR3-$VAR3 --entrypoint python my_image:latest -m unittest discover -v -s test
```

How can I break up the `docker run` command into multiple lines like:

```
docker run \
-e VAR1=$VAR! \
-e VAR2=$VAR2 \
-e $VAR3-$VAR3 \
--entrypoint python my_image:latest \
-m unittest discover -v -s test
```

I've tried using the `|` operator for yaml, but CircleCI was unable to parse because it expects `override` to be a list.

```
# Customize test commands
test:
  override: |
    docker run \
      -e VAR1=$VAR! \
      -e VAR2=$VAR2 \
      -e $VAR3-$VAR3 \
      --entrypoint python my_image:latest \
      -m unittest discover -v -s test
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790454/in-yaml-how-do-i-break-a-string-over-multiple-lines) which details the various ways to break up a string over multiple lines in yaml, I was able to deduce a solution which works nicely.

Note the use of the `>-` operator in the `override` section.

```
test:
  override:
    - >-
      docker run
      -e VAR1=$VAR!
      -e VAR2=$VAR2
      -e $VAR3-$VAR3
      --entrypoint python my_image:latest
      -m unittest discover -v -s test
```

This generates a nice single-line command of:

```
docker run -e VAR1=$VAR! -e VAR2=$VAR2 -e $VAR3-$VAR3 --entrypoint python my_image:latest -m unittest discover -v -s test
```